# Why use $active over var active in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables

Is there any advantage in using a `$` in front of a variable? Does this make it a special variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it's only a naming convention. Some people use it to denote that it's a `jQuery` object (eg `var $this = $(this);`)